# Single shared viewmodel for fragments in viewpager2 or nested viewmodels (one parent and one child-viewmodel pr fragment)?

Tags: android, kotlin, design-patterns, viewmodel, android-architecture-components

I have a main fragment with a map, and below the map is a viewpager2 with several tabs/fragments. The tabs show different information depending on user location.

I see 2 possible designs:

1. One single shared viewmodel with all the data-logic. It's gonna be somewhat big and somewhat messy, because the only shared data among the fragments is the name of the location.
2. A shared viewmodel parent with the name of the location, and then one viewmodel pr fragment that reads the location from the shared viewmodel parent and then handles the data-logic of the individual fragment.

Or is there a better way to do it?

Thanks

Comment: Seems that what I'm looking for is MVVM architecture.

Comment: Could you get any useful help about that? Because I'm currently wondering the exact same thing. what's the best solution for that?